# Firebase "putFile()" for more than one file at a time (Kotlin)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, firebase-storage

I'm working on a way to pass multiple files (in one go) to the firebase storage. To do so, I'm using the `putFile()` method. This method works perfectly with 1 file, but I'm struggling to get it to work for multiple files (that are stored in an `ArrayList`) at a time. Below is the logic I have used (I know it's wrong. Any help is much appreciated):

1. Store files that I want to pass to the storage folder in an `ArrayList`
2. Using a `for-loop`, iterate through the said `ArrayList` and put items at `[i]` --changes
3. In an `OnSuccessListener` for 2, `downloadUrl`
4. Initialise an `ArrayList` to store the `downloadUrl` result
5. In an `OnSuccessListener` for 3, add the downloaded url from 3 into an updated `ArrayList`, only if the current position (i) is == `ArrayList.size-1`. I use this so that there aren't any duplicated instances every single time that the method is called (i.e. when the loop runs), but the method is only called when the first 4 (above) are done
6. Call a method that uploads the `ArrayList` generated from 5 (+ other things) to a rtdb

**Below is the code I have written:**

```
    for (i in 0 until arrayList.size){
        storageRef.putFile(arrayList[i])
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                Log.d("TAG", "Successfully uploaded file: ${it.metadata?.path}")

                storageRef.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { it ->
                    it.toString()
                    Log.d("TAG", "File location: $it")
                    
                    updatedArrayList.add(it.toString())

                    if (i == arrayList.size){                   
                        //method that creates an instance of an object and passes data to the rtdb (firebase)
                        createInstanceUploadToFirebase(id, updatedArrayList)
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

The issue with the above is that I now get the following error when I try to access (load the file using the generated `downloadUrl`) the files (apart from the last one) using the `downloadUrl` and only seem to have access to the item at the very last index:

```
    {
      "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Permission denied."
      }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated(:

Comment: A successfully generated download URL should *never* give a 403, since it gives public access to the file. If you log `it.toString()` and try to open that URL in the browser, can you access the file?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I tried to load the url using my browser and it gives me the same error. I don't know if it's something to do with my nested `if` statement

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure. Hopefully somebody else sees what might be causing this.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen no worries, thanks for having a look(: Do you know if there's any other way to accomplish the task?

Comment: Check your Firebase Storage security rules. You might have denied incoming requests.

Comment: @ArpitShukla you're right, it was to do with security rules. I updated them and now I can get viewable URLs, but the issue is that now, instead of having URLs that point to separate files, all of the generated URLs point to the exact same file (which is not the way I stored them in the input ArrayList). Do you have any idea what could be causing the issue?

Comment: That's because you are uploading all files to the same `storageRef`. You need to put all files to different locations.

Comment: Also, you are iterating from `i=0` to `i=arrayList.size-1`, so the condtion `i == arrayList.size` will never be true. I guess you should check `updatedArrayList.size == arrayList.size`

Comment: @ArpitShukla Ah! great catch - thanks a lot for pointing that out. About the solution for the URLs, I tried using `if`-statements and there was a noticeable lag. Do you know if there's an efficient way to do it?

Comment: There was a lag because of `if` conditions? I didn't get that. What do you mean?

Comment: @ArpitShukla year, there is a significant lag, even though it is working. I'll find ways to optimize it. Thanks for the help(:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue wasn't with the logic, it was to do with the security rules for the storage. This is how I resolved the problem:

**Update storage security rules to:**

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow write: if request.auth != null; 
      allow read;
    }
  }
}
```

**Reason for the error detailed in the question:**
The default read and write rules only allow users to read from the storage if they're authenticated. Changing this by using the above storage rules should fix the issue.